# Why's my controller giving me a failed response via my endpoint?

Tags: php, laravel, debugging, post

I'm trying to make a POST request with params in terms of a file upload and user text upon user clicking Submit.  However, I keep getting a failed response via the `dd();` (which's coming from the API endpoint I've received) for some reason even though I get the file upload success message defined by the flash.  What am I doing wrong in my controller?

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Zttp\Zttp;

class FileUploadController extends Controller {
    public function index(){
        return view('view/index');
    }

    public function uploadFile(Request $request) {
        $userText = $request->input('userText'); // grabbing text area input that user inputs

        if ($request->input('submit') != null ){

            $file = $request->file('file'); // file user wants to upload

            // File Details
            $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $fileSize = $file->getSize();

            // Valid File Extensions
            $valid_extension = ["jpg", "jpeg", "png", "bmp"];

            // 10MB in Bytes
            $maxFileSize = 10485760;

            // Check file extension
            if(in_array(strtolower($extension),$valid_extension)) {
                // Check file size
                if($fileSize <= $maxFileSize){
                    $request->session()->flash('message','Upload Successful.');
                    $response = Zttp::post("https://myendpoint.com/upload.php", [
                        'one' => 'some text',
                        'two', 'some other text',
                        'three' => $filename,
                        'four' => $userText
                    ]);

                    $responseJson = $response->json(); // parses json response into an array for you
                    dd($responseJson);
                } else {
                    $request->session()->flash('message','File too large. File must be less than 2MB.');
                }

            } else {
                $request->session()->flash('message','Invalid File Extension.');
            }
        }
        // Redirect to index
        return redirect()->action('FileUploadController@index');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit of a red herring. It's not your controller giving the failed response. Whatever's going on at the endpoint is living in a seperate request and the error lives there.

Additionally – your flash message declares the upload successful *before* your controller posts anything to your endpoint.

```
<?php
// ...
$request->session()->flash('message','Upload Successful.');
$response = Zttp::post("https://myendpoint.com/upload.php", [/* */]);
```

I reccommend you parse the `$response` more thoroughly and only set the flash message if the response code is `2XX`.

Any debugging re: a failed response at that endpoint will rely on more info, including the response itself, and the nature of the endpoint. (Is it also yours? A third party API?)

Comment: I actually put the flash message underneath the post request but I'm still getting the failed response from the endpoint.  My bad for not mentioning that in my original post.  I think I know what to do now, thanks!

Comment: Of course - and be sure to wrap your `flash()` method in something that's conditional on the endpoint's response, or it'll keep saying it updated, so long as the filesize was appropriate.